# How do I copy a directory from one Jenkins job workspace to another?

Tags: jenkins

I want to copy a complete directory (with all subdirectories) from a workspace in a job *a* into another job *b*'s workspace.

I try with artifact but I don't find a way to copy all subdirectories and there is no option to preserve directory structure.

Answer (score 4):

For artifact archiving, use `**/*` to copy all workspace files and subdirectories

For the Copy Artifacts step in other job, you can leave it blank to copy all artifacts, or you can use `**/*` syntax again

Answer (score 1):

If the directory is very large or has a lot of files, it might be better to archive the source workspace directory using something like `zip` and archive the resulting zip file. Jenkins is notoriously slow at archiving artifacts, so even though you should be able to do it all with individual files, I myself have found moving a single (often much smaller) zip file has much better performance.